# Should strong RSA key with SHA1 self-signature in public key to be considered weak?

Tags: rsa, signature, pgp

Older RSA-4096 GPG keys generated when SHA1 still thought to be acceptable have public key self-signed with SHA1. Shall this considered to be weak key? And with what arguments? AFAIK, GPG key ids are still use SHA1. So, maybe this is not major issue either, because other party will have full public key anyway.